# jquery: toggle function doesn't 'hide' the same way it was 'shown'

Tags: jquery, html, css

New to jquery here and I'm trying to use the toggle function to show and hide a div, while also adding an active class and removing an active class.

http://jsfiddle.net/MAky9/

I'm having 2 problems:

1) the 'active' class won't toggle off when you click the link to close the div, it says highlighted.

2) When you toggle the div closed by clicking the link again, the div doesn't animate up to close it just disappears. How can I get the animation when i toggle show to work when I toggle close?

Would really appreciate any help, thanks a lot!

Comment: I removed the first parameter, the zero, from the toggle call, and it seems to now have the behaviour you are asking for.  It that right?

Comment: You should use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`. jQuery doesn't automatically handle reversing any actions you take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/MAky9/1/

I removed the 0 from the toggle calls, and I switched addClass() to toggleClass()

I also tweaked some styles so I could see what's happening.